# Warn when people link to GitHub but not a specific commit

Tags: feature-request, external-links

Often, people link to relevant source code on GitHub.

Many times - the link is to line numbers on the `master` branch. After some time, the code on the repository is updated and the link goes out of sync - pointing to something completely irrelevant.

A simple regex that checks links to GitHub for the master branch, and a comment suggesting linking to a specific commit instead would go a long way in preventing this situation. I've ran into this at least 3 times before so I figured it's worth an issue.

Comment: If relevant information is lost when the link dies / changes / whatever the code should be in the question itself to begin with

Comment: This is normal link rot, and the general advice here is: quote in addition to link. No GitHub-specific functionality needed.

Comment: It is normal link rot - but we can help it. For example of one of my own see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23363285/1348195

Comment: Here is another example of links that add content but are not needed for the answer for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987896/how-does-bluebirds-util-tofastproperties-function-make-an-objects-properties/24989927#24989927 has plenty of links, they're not _needed_ but they contribute.

Comment: Similarly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127493/python-how-to-overwrite-output-from-markdown-library/22130024#22130024 is one I ran into last night; the code itself isn't relevant to the answer, but the code being used *as a documentation resource* is.

Answer (score 11):

Any links, even if towards a specific line in a specific GitHub commit, are subject to link rot. The appropriate response is to include the relevant code in the post itself and educate OPs to do that.

Comment: However, I'm not against adding warnings for when that happens, just skeptical about the impact.

Comment: Right, but we can help it. We can prevent the link rot in this case or at least make it much much much rarer. Links to external sources _in addition to including code_ are relevant. "How does feature X work in library Y" is a valid and often useful question.

Comment: and the most important part, is that it takes the user only [one extra key press](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/)(`y`) to get the canonical link